# SystemC binding a socket to a port

Tags: systemc

I have a virtual model given to me by one of the vendors. This model has a port for interrupt and I want to connect it to my interrupt controller.
The problem is that the port in my interrupt controller is a socket and I can't bind them together.

This is the error I get:
sc_main.cpp:30:65: error: no match for call to '(sc_core::sc_vector<sc_core::sc_out >::element_type {aka sc_core::sc_out}) (tlm::tlm_target_socket<1, tlm::tlm_base_protocol_types, 1, (sc_core::sc_port_policy)1>&)'
gem_eth_ctrl.m_ethernet_intq0;

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to bind a port to a socket that way. You can only bind a port with another port of same interface type or a channel of same type. If possible, modify your interrupt controller block to change the socket to an input port and turn your *_transport() into an SC_THREAD.